# Installation apk file on Android device, ADB part missing and Error

Tags: android, c, installation, adb, raylib

I try to build simple_game from templates to Android and install it on an Android device.
But I have a problem with installation to Android devices, especially with the ADB part.

[Simple_game](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/templates)

I use the manual to build at:

[Build manual](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-for-Android)

but I have a little bit of trouble with the last step.

When I connect my Android device to PC a use command prompt to step into simple_game directory and run

ADB devices

PC see Android device, this device is in device list. I have set developer mode on Android device, installed new driver to see device for PC, set USB debugging and confirmed use this Android device with PC.

After this, I run the command

```
mingw32-make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_ANDROID
```

but the part in Makefile.Android with ADB doesn't work.

Here is last echo in screen

```
C:\open-jdk/bin/jarsigner -keystore android.simple_game/simple_game.keystore -storepass raylib -keypass raylib -signedjar android.simple_game/bin/simple_game.signed.apk android.simple_game/bin/simple_game.unsigned.apk simple_gameKey
jar signed.

Warning:
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
C:/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/zipalign -f 4 android.simple_game/bin/simple_game.signed.apk simple_game.apk
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/raylib/raylib/templates/simple_game'

C:\raylib\raylib\templates\simple_game>


When I try run adb separatly, I get error

C:\RAYLIB\templates\simple_game>adb install simple_game.apk
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install simple_game.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.raylib.rgame-G49JemMPBwfUFp_sJK7aFQ==: Package /data/app/com.raylib.rgame-G49JemMPBwfUFp_sJK7aFQ==/base.apk code is missing]

C:\RAYLIB\templates\simple_game>
```

Do anyone know how to fix this problem and succesufuly install apk file to android device?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try the following:

1.Connect android device to PC using USB cable and ensure "file transfer" mode is enabled.
2.Activate developer settings in your device.
3.Enable USB debugging on your device.
4.Android studio should detect your device in ADB manager.

On running the app an apk file will be created on your android device and you can run the app from there.